# Save all xml nodes to db without looping through it

Tags: xml, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have this xml:

```
<Path>
  <Record>
     <ID>6534808</ID>
     <Distance>1.05553036073736</Distance>
  </Record>
  <Record>
     <ID>6542471</ID>
     <Distance>1.05553036073736</Distance>
  </Record>
  ... and about more 500 nodes
</Path>
```

And I'm using the code below to get all "Record" nodes:

```
XmlNodeList paths = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Record");
```

And, after that, I save each record to database. But, the problem is that I'm using a foreach to loop through this nodes and the count of this nodes may be more than 500, sometimes it gets up to 1000 "Records" node. And this gets too long...

Is there a way to save all of these nodes without looping through it?

Thanks!!

Comment: XmlNodeList is a class in the .NET framework´s DOM implementation, not in the LINQ to XML implementation so I am not sure why you have tagged the question as LINQ to XML. If you use LINQ to XML and want to efficiently pull in long documents then see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387008%28v=VS.90%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can iterate with your current for-each, but my suggestion is don't save the data to a record per each iteration.

First create the insert statements, then batch execute all inserts in a single trip. This is more efficient.

In the other hand, maybe you're using some OR/M. If this is your situation, and your choice is NHibernate, it supports batching commands.

**You've even another cleaner, and efficient solution: XSLT.**

Convert your XML to SQL with a very simple XSLT instead of iterating nodes from C#. Parsing your XML to SQL with that XSLT is the fastest and best solution, and you can send the data in a single trip too.